# Why do not we carry energy as DC in dams?

Tags: power, ac, dc, transmission-line

If a wire's DC resistance is less than AC resistance, which it is, why do we carry energy as AC in dams? (high resistance means high loss, why do we carry it with higher losses?) Why don't we carry DC?

Comment: It's really tricky to convert DC voltage efficiently. It easy to convert AC voltage and you often just use higher AC voltage to reduce the current for the same power. Halving the current reduces losses by a lot more than halving cable resistance.

Comment: What do you mean by dams?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current - the "advantages" and "disadvantages" sections might have some answers for you

Comment: I think the wikipedia article pointed out by @Wesley gives extensive answer to your question.

Comment: ""If a wire's DC resistance is less than AC resistance, which it is""  No, it isn't.

Comment: AC losses are worse than DC loses given the same size conductor and length.  One reason for the increase loss with 60 Hz is because of the skin depth (which is 1/3" for copper) effect.  This means that ~63% of the current is carried in the outer 1/3" of the conductor.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that by "dams" you mean **hydro-electric power stations**.

Within a power generating station losses are low because the distances are short. There is no benefit to using DC internally in the power station.

DC comes into its own on long distance transmission or undersea transmission where the cost of AC-DC-AC conversion is offset by the savings due to more efficient transmission.

Answer (score 1):

The limit for DC generators is around 150kW.  This is because the armature for generator (or motor), must carry the full current.  For the same size power, ac generators are smaller, cheaper and easier to maintain.  So given the fact we are generating MW or GW, dc generation is out.

High-voltage dc transmission is used rarely, but this is mainly to allow difference in sychronization between source grid and load grid.  The source and load do not have to be sychronized (as in, the three-phase waveforms start at the same time).

Quebec, Canada uses a DC link to transfer power from James Bay to eastern seaboard of the US.  Newfoundland and Labrador, Canada will use a DC link to send power from the Lower Churchill in Labrador to the island of Newfoundland.

From [A new training simulator for improved voltage control of the Hydro-Quebec system](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4126309_A_new_training_simulator_for_improved_voltage_control_of_the_Hydro-Quebec_system)

[image: ydro-Quebec 735-kV transmission system]

But these cases are rare.  The majority of tranmission is ac because we can easily step-up  voltages for transmission and step-down voltages for consumption via transformers.  We cannot do this with DC.

Generate ac power at 20kV, step up to 735kV for transmission, step down to 13kV for local transmission, 1kV for neighborhoods and 120V/240V or 120V/208V for consumers.  Large transformers have efficiencies above 95%-98%.  So most of the generated power gets to the consumers.

High voltage DC transmission may be more efficient than ac transmission because current flows through the full conductor rather than on surface (skin effect), but the problem is ac must be converted into dc (losses) and dc must be converted into ac (losses), so it is only cost effective if large amounts of power is being transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

In Brazil there are long distance line projects which carry energy as DC.
Itapipu is a hydroelectric than power supplies Brazil and Bolivia, the line that connects the two countries carry energy as DC, because in Brazil we use 60HZ and in Bolivia they uses 50Hz.